# Can you help me with this Error Message?

Tags: java, netbeans, ireport

Error loading the report template

Message:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 145; columnNumber: 39;
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'paragraph'. No child element is expected at this point.
>   Level:
>       SEVERE Stack Trace: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 145; columnNumber: 39; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was
>   found starting with element 'paragraph'. No child element is expected
>   at this point.
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:243)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:226)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:214)
>       com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlLoader.reloadJasperDesign(JrxmlLoader.java:73)
>       com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlVisualView.run(JrxmlVisualView.java:512)
>       org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1432)
>       org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2042)
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'paragraph'. No child element is expected at this point.
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:458)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3237)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1800)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:766)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:355)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2770)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>       com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
>       org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1647)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:239)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:226)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:214)
>       com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlLoader.reloadJasperDesign(JrxmlLoader.java:73)
>       com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlVisualView.run(JrxmlVisualView.java:512)
>       org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1432)
>       org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2042)

Error Message:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: /* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12 */

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to provide you with help.

Comment: It's not a question but a error message.

Comment: Btw, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: i know how to learn mysql store procedure

Comment: @user1858333: follow the link I provided and find what you've made wrong

Comment: how do we know which is your line no. 12?

Comment: @user1858333: This is too bad. You completely changed your posting. Earlier you posted this question as issue with `stored procedure` and got an answer accepted on `'2014-04-23 06:38:15Z'`. Now after a long time, you edited the same posting and changed the question and then unaccepted the answer. That is ridiculous. Instead, you should have posted the error stacktrace as a new posting.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compile the stored procedure with multiple executable statements terminated by default statement terminator, the `;` semicolon.

Define a custom `delimiter` and use it to send to compiler. So that the compiler understands the entire body as a *code block* with multiple statements.

**Example**:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE aProce()
BEGIN
    SELECT
        th.NAME,
        th.PRICEBUY,
        th.PRICESELL,
        p.DATENEW
    FROM shop.stockdiary AS p
    JOIN shop.products AS th where
        th.id = p.Product;
END;

//

delimiter ;
```

**Alternatively**:
This is only applicable if there exists a single executable statement in the procedure body.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE aProce()
    SELECT
        th.NAME,
        th.PRICEBUY,
        th.PRICESELL,
        p.DATENEW
    FROM shop.stockdiary AS p
    JOIN shop.products AS th where
        th.id = p.Product;
```